# jquery selection to post value

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to grab the contents of a div and pass it to a php script that emails it. So I need to use a $('#div').html() and send that to a $_POST[''] value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

(From jQuery's [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   //your PHP file
   url: "some.php",
   //passing contents $_POST['body'] will be your body.
   data: "body=" + $('#div').html(),
   //msg is your PHP scripts' response
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you may also want to try this:

```
$.post('ajax/sendEmail.php',
    { body : $('#div').html() }, 
    function(msg) { 
        alert("Email was sent: " + msg);
    });
```